# failed to insert data into putsql?

Tags: apache-nifi

I try to insert json into putsql while inserting I have an following issue?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You have set an attribute named "detail", because that's what ${detail} will be looking for. If you want to explicitly use the "detail" table, just put "detail" as the table name in ConvertJSONToSQL. If it is supposed to be dynamic, you'll need to set an attribute named "detail" with the value of the table you want